# Does XAML have a conditional compiler directive for debug mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need something like this for styles in XAML :

```
<Application.Resources>

#if DEBUG
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
    </Style>
#else
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>
    </Style>
#endif

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I need to have different styles in debug mode, so that i could make a lighter execution in debug mode.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I recently had to do this and was suprised at how simple it was when I couldn't easily find any clear examples.  What I did was add the following to AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition( "debug-mode", "Namespace" )]
#endif
```

Then, use the markup-compatability namespace's AlternateContent tag to choose your content based on the presense of that namespace definition:

```
<Window x:Class="Namespace.Class"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="debug-mode"

        Width="400" Height="400">

        ...

        <mc:AlternateContent>
            <mc:Choice Requires="d">
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                </Style>
            </mc:Choice>
            <mc:Fallback>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft"/>
                </Style>
            </mc:Fallback>
        </mc:AlternateContent>

        ...
</Window>
```

Now, when DEBUG is defined, "debug-mode" will also be defined, and the "d" namespace will be present.  This makes the AlternateContent tag choose the first block of code.  If DEBUG is not defined, the Fallback block of code will be used.

This sample code was not tested, but it's basically the same thing that I'm using in my current project to conditionally show some debug buttons.

I did see a blog post with some example code that relied on the "Ignorable" tag, but that seemed a lot less clear and easy to use as this method.

Comment: This is really cool and easy. And the RELEASE build's baml resources really do not contain any artefacts of all this. I enriched some ToolTip-StackPanels with additional DEBUG information this way.

Comment: The VS error pane does not like this, although everything is working as expected: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459716/alternatecontent-tags-causing-issues-with-ide-but-not-compiler)

Comment: Perfect...very simple

Comment: My solution fails to compile when I add the code to AssemblyInfo.cs. I get `The type or namespace name 'XmlnsDefinitionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. What can I do?

Comment: ```XmlnsDefinitionAttribute``` is in the ```System.Windows.Markup``` namespace.  This namespace is in the ```System.Xaml.dll``` assembly, which I believe is added automatically when you create a WPF project in visual studio.

Comment: @Flipper Add line "using System.Windows.Markup;" to AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: @Sheen not working on Windows Phone 8.1 project: "Markup does not exists in System.Windows" (sorry for being OT for this question)

Comment: Strange that the red error underline was going wild for this block (mc:AlternateContent) on VS, but it worked anyway.

Comment: If you use a feature between AlternateContent which adds code to IComponentConnector.Connect method (event handlers like OnClick do) the connectionIds get totally f*cked up and InitializeComponent will either fail at runtime or do unexpected things (mix up event handlers).

Comment: Please see [WPF AlternateContent not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150073/wpf-alternatecontent-not-working) for troubleshooting. Apparently, you should use AssemblyInfo file from another assembly.

Comment: The name "AlternateContent" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006". [here](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/8b1e369e-191f-4ef5-a637-0ebc9b26e846?category=metrotools) I have found a link to someone having the same problem. It seems like the above guys [WPF Alternate... not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150073/wpf-alternatecontent-not-working) seem to find `AlternateContext`inside the namespace. Which here isn't the case. Anyone here with similar problems?

Comment: I have started a new Question for [the issue I just described](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362985/c-sharp-wpf-alternatecontext-doesnt-exist-in-the-namespace)

Comment: Note that you may need to mark "mc" Ignorable against itself, i.e., mc:Ignorable="d mc"

Comment: Any idea why in Xamarin i get this error `Type mc:Choice not found in xmlns http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006`?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in WPF/Silverlight/WP7.

On an interesting note, the standards document, [ISO/IEC 29500](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59578) (*Office Open XML File Formats*), covers how this should be handled in an XML document, and XAML does support one of the items from that spec `mc:Ignorable` which allows us to do things like this:

```
<Page xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:c="Comments"
      mc:Ignorable="c">
    <Button Content="Some Text"
            c:Content="Some other text" />
</Page>
```

to comment out attributes.

The XAML parser team (SL4, WP7.1, WPF) chose to use that spec to solve their needs for ignoring attributes, rather than just making something up. That is why some of the default XAML pages have the 'mc' namespace defined. I do think it would be cool if XAML one day supported the rest of the spec that allows the loading of alternate content.

The `mc:Ignorable` attribute is used by Blend to support design time functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a template selector. The DataTemplateSelector class is something you code. With the template selection method that you override, you could put your preprocessor directives.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

Comment: A `DataTemplateSelector` might be relevant if the question was about alternate *view content*, but it is about alternate *styles* - there is no "selector" for alternate styles. Well, you could create two separate copies of the content, using different styles... but that doesn't sound like what you are trying to say here.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't happy with any of these and did this:

In my XAML I put any attributes or tags with a space just so i know I am screwing with them in the .cs file.

```
<Window x:Class="...
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="" 
    BorderThickness="2"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Height="200" 
    Width="500"
    
    WindowStyle="None"    
    >
```

then in my code behind I do this:

```
    public partial class ScanProgressWindow : Window
    {
        public ScanProgressWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 #if DEBUG
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
 #endif
        }
    }
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the given answers aren't the easiest to use. Here is my solution using a custom attachable dependency property:

```
using namespace Utility{
    public static class DebugVisibility
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Debug", typeof(bool?), typeof(DebugVisibility), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool?), IsVisibleChangedCallback));

        private static void IsVisibleChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe == null)
                return;
#if DEBUG
            fe.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
#else
            fe.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
#endif
        }

        public static void SetIsVisible(DependencyObject element, bool? value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool? GetIsVisible(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (bool?)element.GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

and the xaml would be used like this:

```
<window ... xmlns:Util="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Utility" >
    <Label Util:DebugVisibility.IsVisible="True">
</window>
```

I kept it as a bool in case you wanted to add some other visibility logic in there. This is a nice simple toggle that can be bound to and attached to any control

Comment: Good idea, but the implementation can be *much* simpler. Debug/Release obviously does not change in the middle of a run, so you don't need all the Binding/Dependency stuff. All you need is a static variable "Debug" in Util, that is True when Debug, and False when not. (And for convenience, a second static "Release" that is False when Debug.)  Then do `<Label IsVisible={Static Util:Debug}`.

Comment: NOTE: This answer isn't the same as "conditional compilation"; `IsVisible=False` means the view objects are created (though no layout call). This has some cost, though often a minor one - so is okay for some purposes.  Its not useful *for this specific question*, which is about alternative *styles* - IsVisible is not helpful there.

Comment: BTW, if you based your code on an example you saw somewhere else, you should provide a link to credit the author whose code helped you create this. It looks like the complexity is there so that VS designer can see that change, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36151130/199364); if that is the reason for the complexity, then you should mention that.