# XAML Conditionally Add DataTemplate / ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, conditional-statements

I'm working on an application where I am trying to support .NET 4.0 Users as well as use some of the newer 4.5.1 stuff for my up to date users.  Some of the stuff in 4.5.1 is 100% incompatible with the .NET 4.0 stuff.  I'm handling this in my C# code using #if statements.  From what I understand XAML has no equivalent of this.

Is it possible to conditionally load a DataTemplate /  resource dictionary?  I have a Data Template like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type net45:Net45OnlyObject}">
   <StackPanel>
         <!-- My Custom XAML Herel -->
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I attempt to build with my .NET 4.0 configuration It tells me that my "net45" namespace doesn't exist, and the name "Net45OnlyObject" doesn't exist in "net45".

Is there any way I can structure that DataTemplate to be ignored when using my .NET 4.0 Configuration?

I'm using C# and WPF.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19940157/1018140

Comment: Thank You, but unfortunately that won't help.  In my case I can't compile my DataTemplate, because the object I'm referencing doesn't exist in the current configuration. It's not just a case of wanting to display something different when in a separate configuration. Am I explaining that clearly?