# AlternateContent Tags causing issues with IDE, but not compiler

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012, ide, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a legacy product.  I need to make regions of a complex UI optional, based on build constants.  It is not feasible to move these regions into controls, so I am using AlternateContent Tags (mc:AlternateContent).

This works perfectly, at compilation and the application runs as expected.

However, the IDE claims one error for each AlternateContent, and enclosed Choice Tag, and will not load the Design window/preview (in VS or Blend):

```
The name "AlternateContent" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
The name "Choice" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

I have tried, rebuilding, cleaning and rebuilding, changing build settings between release, debug, x86, x64, and rebooting.  Nothing helps.  It even give the same errors in Blend.

I am hoping that this is just something stupid that I am doing, and I can fix it; or possibly a newer Namespace URI I should be using.  If I cannot resolve the errors, I am hoping someone knows a trick to suppress these errors in the IDE, so can use it.

I have a fully updated VS2013 Premium installation.  However, It has the glitch on a test machine running VS14 CTP, and another running VS2012 (fully updated), both without any add-ins; so I have to assume it is not a problem with my PCs install.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I also get the same issue on several PC's and I'm struggling to find a resolution..

Comment: VS2013 update 3 still is not able to handle this -- designer just says "invalid markup"

Comment: That tag appears to be part of the Microsoft Office 2010 / 2013 SDK. Do you have one of those SDKs installed on the development machine? Another possibility is that you are dealing with machines that don't have .NET 3.5 installed, which Office appears to need. Or building against .NET 4.0 vs .NET 4.5 can cause issues. Or 32-bit vs 64-bit. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx describes several scenarios. If you find one that is the issue, please post it as an answer and mark it as such.

Comment: VS2015 designer still cannot handle this -- everybody should send a frown feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: VS2017 XAML editor still squiggles these constructions.

Comment: Raised an issue here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24238 and here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/182354/alternatecontent-tag-in-xaml-causes-ide-error-but.html

Comment: Simply add MC like this (mc:Ignorable="d mc") in <Usercontrol/> tag attribut

Answer (score 9):

A little late to the party, but if you add the mc tag to your Ignorable attribute the error goes away. Your content won't show in the designer but worked for me when I compiled the different flavours of my project.

```
<UserControl...
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:conditional="defined-in-assembly.cs"
    mc:Ignorable="d mc"/>
```

Comment: Question: Did you read anything further than the word "AlternateContent" from within subject/title or body?

Comment: Sure. Did you read past the comma in my answer? By adding mc to the mc:Ignorable line, the IDE no longer complains about the AlternateContent or Choice tags, because it ignores them. As I said it won't actually show your AlternateContent in the designer, but when you compile and run it it will work as expected (like it does even when the errors are showing in Visual Studio). It just ignores the error and at least allows you to see and modify the rest of the layout. Not perfect, but works for me.

Comment: ... and was also something the OP was after > "If I cannot resolve the errors, I am hoping someone knows a trick to suppress these errors in the IDE, so can use it."

Comment: Shame on me, you are absolutely right. I was so sure I had used mc:Ignorable that I didn't check again. But honestly it looks very weird to use a "mc" namespace feature to ignore the mc namespace itself; has a smell of time machine paradoxon.

Comment: the only point where this doesn't work, is when you need the conditional stuff to be available for the designer. You might have a look at [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362985/c-sharp-wpf-alternatecontext-doesnt-exist-in-the-namespace?noredirect=1#comment73787809_43362985)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class BuildConstants
{
    public bool IsDebug
    {
        get
        {
#if DEBUG
            return true;
#else
            return false;
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Name="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    <l:BuildConstants x:Key="BuildConstants" />
</Application.Resources>

<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsDebug, Source={StaticResource BuildConstants}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="This will be visible only when DEBUG build constant is present"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The whole reason of using AlternateContent is to ensure the content is stripped out of the XAML, eg if you use a decompiler there is no way to undo the change or add it back in. If you do as you suggested you could edit the assembly and change the IsDebug flag to be whatever you want.