# c# WPF AlternateContent doesn't exist in the Namespace [...]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

I am facing the need to have XAML Code only in design-time. I have found a nice Solution to this, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940157/4099159). It seems like there are a few guys having a Problem with the parse-timing of `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` which is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36151477/4099159).

In my case the issue is really, that I cannot compile my code, because `AlternateContent` can't be found in the namespace `xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`. I haven't found any documentation to this namespace indeed and it seems strange, that the line `mc:Ignorable="d"`doesn't fail to build, which means I have at least one assembly containing the above namespace.

This is my Code:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("debug-mode", "MyNamespace")]
#endif

<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.SomeWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:debug="debug-mode"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ... >
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <mc:AlternateContent>
                    <mc:Choice Requires="debug">
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles;component/Generic.xaml" />
                    </mc:Choice>
                </mc:AlternateContent>
                ...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

My guess is, that I'm missing an Assembly-Reference, but I've not yet found a Documentation specifying a containing Assembly for `AlternateContent`. Do you have any ideas how I might get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940157/4099159) to work?

#### Edit:

It seems like this is a common VS Problem which can be solved by this `mc:Ignorable="d mc"`. This just doesn't work in my case, because I would need this to include Resources at Design-Time, which should be available to the VS-Designer :)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459716/alternatecontent-tags-causing-issues-with-ide-but-not-compiler). Basically,try to add `mc` to the `Ignorable`tag

Comment: @Pikoh this would work if I didn't need this stuff to be available for the designer.

Comment: I don't get why you rejected my edit. Is `AlternateContext` really a thing in WPF? I couldn't find any references about it.

Comment: @polfosol my bad, i must have lost my head somewhere in the endless skies of code :) - Of course it should say `AlternateContent` everywhere.

Comment: No problem! But still, the title is the most important part, as it affects the search results. Please fix that too.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a common VS problem which can be solved by this code

```
mc:Ignorable="d mc"
```

This must be added to the root element of the view.
Note: that you already should have `mc:Ignorable="d"` in your root element, so you have to just add the `mc` to it.