# How to write XAML + C# code to be compiled only in Debug Mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've got some serious question about a thing that's not an error, but code quality issue. Currently I'm using one VS2013 solution to cover both Debug and Release versions of my program. As far as I know, using this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

before a method solves problem of excess C# code in code-behind, but what about excess XAML? I'd like get rid of this code in XAML:

```
<HubSection x:Name="debug" Header="debug">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button x:Name="testowy_button" Content="Test: plik lokalny." Click="TestOne" />
                <Button x:Name="testowy_button_2" Content="Test: biblioteka." Click="TestTwo" />
                <Button Content="Test: z wewnątrz wątku tła." Click="TestBackground" />
                <Button Content="Zrzut playlisty do Debugu." Click="CommandToDump" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

And by *getting rid* I don't mean setting it as Visibility.Hidden, which is very easy. How to exclude some XAML from compilation in Release? Any ideas?

Best regards. :)

Answer (score 0):

For C# code, you can use the `#if DEBUG` [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

For XAML: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode)

Comment: For setting any part of C# code, of course #IF DEBUG works perfectly.

But considering XAML, adding a namespace, unfortunately, works only for styles and such things. Still, not solved. :(