# WPF AlternateContent not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to show different view elements in a WPF control in debug and release configurations for testing purposes. I have used this post as a guide:
[Does XAML have a conditional compiler directive for debug mode? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode)

In order to test it, I have created a VS2013 solution with a single WPF app project, called TestingAlternateContent. Inside my AssemblyInfo.cs I have added the following code:

```
#if DEBUG
    [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("debug-mode", "TestingAlternateContent")]
#endif
```

In my MainWindow.xaml I have created a simple code sample to test this behaviour as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingAlternateContent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:debug="debug-mode"        
        mc:Ignorable="mc debug" 

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <mc:AlternateContent>
            <mc:Choice Requires="debug">
                <TextBlock Text="Debug mode!!" />
            </mc:Choice>
            <mc:Fallback>
                <TextBlock Text="Release mode here!" />
            </mc:Fallback>
        </mc:AlternateContent>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

While testing this, I always see the window with the "Release mode here!" message, regardless which configuration (Debug, Relase) I am using. I have checked that the AssemblyInfo #if DEBUG is working propperly, changing accordingly when I change between Debug/Release configurations.
I  have tested the same code under VS2008/VS2013 with .NET Framework 3.5/4.5 versions, and none have worked.
What am I missing? Anyone knows what is wrong here or can post a working code as reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` is parsed after the XAML is parsed, so it doesn't work for the same assembly.

You can however, make that `XmlnsDefinition` in any other (referenced) project in your solution, and it'll work

That is:

- ProjectA (Namespace: `TestingAlternateContent`)

  - Contains your `MainWindow.Xaml`
  - References ProjectB
- ProjectB

  - Contains the `XmlsDefinitionAttribute` with the namespace of `TestingAlternateContent`:

    ```
    #if DEBUG
    [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("debug-mode", "TestingAlternateContent")]
    #endif
    ```

I just tested it, and it works fine, no modifications to either the assembly attribute declaration or to the Xaml, just adding it on a different project

Comment: Thanks, I have read something similar in the meantime, I am going to test this in my case and if it works I will mark your solution as accepted

Comment: Your solution worked as a charm! Thank you very much, really useful trick that saves me a lot of time :)

Comment: YEP. I had to add an empty DLL project for the sole purpose of declaring one XmlnsDefinition because XAML is XML + Magic String + FML.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a nice compiler directive for the XAML designer unfortunately, I've achieved the desired result using an attached property that changes the Visibility propety, it's quite nice because it shows in the designer as well.

```
<Window x:Class="DebugTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DebugTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button local:MainWindow.IsDebugOnly="True" Width="100" Height="100" Content="Debug only"/>
</Grid>
```

The attached property here is in the MainWindow class but it could be in a utility class anywhere you want.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DebugTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public static bool GetIsDebugOnly(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsDebugOnlyProperty);
        }
        public static void SetIsDebugOnly(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsDebugOnlyProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDebugOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDebugOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
        {
            UIElement sender = s as UIElement;
            if (sender != null && e.NewValue != null)
            {
                bool value = (bool)e.NewValue;
                if (value)
                {
#if DEBUG
                    bool isDebugMode = true;
#else
                    bool isDebugMode = false;
#endif

                    sender.Visibility = isDebugMode ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        })));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tnaks for the suggestion, that was another try for me, but in this case I preferred to use separated blocks (the case is a grid with some different elements, so mainly the rows/columns change and define additional elements). I have tested your solution and works fine, so it can be used to fix my problem if the other method doesn't work :)