# Using #warning in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, warnings

Sometimes I use `#warning TEXT` in my C# code.

Now I tried to generate a warning in a .xaml file but it failed.

Regions are working without problems.

Is there any opportunity to do this with warnings too (like `<!-- #warning TEXT -->`)?

Answer (score 2):

`<!-- TEXT -->` is a standard XML comment and it is fine to use such comments in a .xaml file. The compiler will not pay any attention to this, so it is simply for documenting your code and will not work as a conditional directive like #warning in C#.

I do not believe there is an equivalent to #warning for xaml. You will need to put conditional flags in your code behind and then hide / show XAML in the UI accordingly.

Tweaking my interest I just did a little search and found [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode/19940157#19940157) which should get you the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

`#warning` is a preprocessor directive. There is no support for preprocessor directives in XAML