# conditional compile for Namespace in xaml wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to realize something as below. I have read some other articles here on conditional compile for xaml but they are not what I'm after. What I'm looking for is the different namespace for different conditional symbols. Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        #if TEST
        xmlns:CO="clr-namespace:Wpf.TestA;assembly=Wpf.TestA"
        #else
        xmlns:CO="clr-namespace:Wpf.TestB;assembly=Wpf.TestB"
        #endif
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/8732307

Comment: Voted for reopen as the supposed dupe is about conditional compile of resources rather than namespaces -- and the answer for namespaces does not need to use AlternateContent/Choice/Fallback.  Conditional namespace means single control definition can be implemented at runtime by one of multiple assemblies (resolved at compile-time).