# How can I define resources conditionally in a WPF ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, resources

I have the following resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<!--<Color x:Key="Control.Disabled.Background">#F0F0F0</Color>
<Color x:Key="ItemsContainer.SelectedItemColor">#F58220</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.DarkBackground">#08305B</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.LightBackground">#93B8E1</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.MediumDarkBackground">#004283</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.DataRow.DarkBackground">#EBF0F4</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.DataRow.LightBackground">#FFFFFF</Color>-->

<Color x:Key="Control.Disabled.Background">#F0F0F0</Color>
<Color x:Key="ItemsContainer.SelectedItemColor">#F58220</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.DarkBackground">DarkGreen</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.LightBackground">LightGreen</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.MediumDarkBackground">Green</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.DataRow.DarkBackground">#EBF0F4</Color>
<Color x:Key="NBBR.DataRow.LightBackground">#FFFFFF</Color>
```

Currently I have to manually comment and uncomment the blocks that set different colors for our application. But I would like a `#If …. #Then …. #Else … #Endif` like construct that depends on compilation constants.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use 2 seperate files, each containing one color scheme, and let the build system deal with enabling just one of them?

Comment: The answer can be found in this question and its related questions. Works fine! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode