# set visibility of multiple elements in XAML by one variable

Tags: wpf

when working on the design, i want to be a able to control visibility of multiple components i want to be able to control all of the isHidden from a single property.
so far my code looks like this

```
ignoreable="e d"
<StackPanel d:IsHidden=true>
...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel e:IsHidden=false>
...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel d:IsHidden=true>
...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel e:IsHidden=false>
...
</StackPanel>
```

is there any way to control the visibility of all of the panels from a **single** variable?

so it will look like this

```
<StackPanel d:IsHidden=isVisibleVar>
...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel e:IsHidden=isVisibleVarOther>
...
</StackPanel>
```

i'm aware of converters. i know how to do this at runtime, what i want to is have a fast way to switch between visibility of the two groups from one place, instead of search & replace

Comment: What you need is a bool property on your `ViewModel` and a `BoolToVisibility` converter, which I think is included in the `PresentationFramework.dll`, but then again I don't know which .NET Framework you are using? MS has released a converter just for that [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Bind the `Visibility` property of all `StackPanels` to the same source property of put all `StackPanels` in a "parent" panel and bind the `Visibility` property of this one to a source property. Depending on the type of the source property you may need to use a converter to convert the value to a `Visibility` enumeration value.

Comment: @mm8 they are in different panels, i cant group them all under the same one.

Comment: What about my first suggestion then...?

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to switch the Visibility while Design - Time not in runtime?

Comment: @MartinBackasch ,exactly . i have several text blocks around the window that are completely unrelated to each other in terms of their parent elements other then their visibility (lets say demo mode vs production).
i want to be able to switch visibility on those two groups of texts quickly

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same _design-time vs. runtime_. With _design-time_ I mean, when shaping your GUI in the XAML-Designer when the application is not running. But what I assume from you last comment, is that you want to differ between running your application in debug vs. release mode. So may be a look at [Does XAML have a conditional compiler directive for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8732307/5893316) can help you.

Comment: @MartinBackasch , sorry for the mixup but i do mean design time, not debug/runtime.

was trying to provide the justification behind me needing to be able to switch easily between the two visibility modes in design time

Answer (score 0):

found a work around. 
use a style for each group. then i only need to set the visibility in  two locations.

```
<Style x:Key="MainButtonStyle" 
                       TargetType="Button"
                       BasedOn= "{StaticResource BasicButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
</Style>

 <Style x:Key="SecButtonStyle" 
                       TargetType="Button"
                       BasedOn= "{StaticResource BasicButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not be such a high sophisticated one and did not use only a *"single variable"*, but it will do the trick (using *two variables*).

---

So at first you define two variables in your XAML. For example directly in the `Window.Resources` like:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <system:Boolean x:Key="ShowInDemoMode">False</system:Boolean>
        <system:Boolean x:Key="HideInDemoMode">True</system:Boolean>
    </Window.Resources>

    ...

</Window>
```

or - if you have one - in your Style-`ResourceDictionary`

```
<ResourceDictionary ...
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    >

    <system:Boolean x:Key="ShowInDemoMode">False</system:Boolean>
    <system:Boolean x:Key="HideInDemoMode">True</system:Boolean>

    ...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can use the two like this:

```
<StackPanel d:IsHidden="{StaticResource HideInDemoMode}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel d:IsHidden="{StaticResource ShowInDemoMode}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel d:IsHidden="{StaticResource HideInDemoMode}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel d:IsHidden="{StaticResource ShowInDemoMode}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

---

With this static resources you can easily switch between the visibility of your `StackPanel` items by changing the values of these two resources.

---

***Remark:***
*Setting `d:IsHidden` to `true` or `false` is only active in DesignTime and will show the items when running your application, which is a major difference to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491662/5893316).*

Comment: cannot be used because it conflicts with the Visibility property.

Comment: @Danw25: I will try to adjust my answer. Meanwhile can you please update your question, and provide more of your real code, since with your provided code "it works for me". And also if I set the `Visibility` property like `<StackPanel d:IsHidden="{StaticResource HideInDemoMode}" Visibility="Visible"> ...  </StackPanel> `.