# Xamarin conditional xaml based on compilation directive

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need the same as
[Does XAML have a conditional compiler directive for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode/19940157)
but in Xamarin xaml; i've tried the proposed solution but i get this error:

```
Type mc:Choice not found in xmlns http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006
```

I've tried to use xcc https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/xcc, but it seems not working with .netstandard 2.0 / Xamarin.Forms 4.5

Comment: that is a solution for WPF, not Xamarin

Comment: I know, I would like to achieve a similar result in xamarin

Comment: If you want to add the global `style` in the app.xaml, if yes, you can add it like this thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application

Comment: Have you found something so far, (I am looking for the same a conditional build like ignore this xaml line in debug mode), not the design time as the answer mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Its little different in XAML of Xamarin. There is Design time namespacing in Xamarin.

You would use **markup-compatibility** xml name space and mark design namespace as `Ignorable`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" 
             xmlns:ref="clr-namespace:XamUtilities.Views;assembly=XamUtilities" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Class="Sample.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <d:Label Text="This will be displayed only in previewer"/>
        <Label Text="This will be displayed in actual app"/>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In code behind also you can set values

```cs
[DesignTimeVisible (true)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        if (DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled) 
        {
            // Previewer only code  
            //add your bindings in here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this, but i need something to be compiled conditionally in the final apk.