# How to conditionally compile a NuGet package on build in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, conditional-statements, msbuild-task

I'm using a NuGet package in the project. Is there a way to isolate or ignore that NuGet package and use another NuGet package using a compile switch or Macro?

Purpose: This NuGet Package is licensed per developer, So the intent is to disconnect it during the development from other developers.

I have looked into myproject.csproj

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nugetPackage2Exclude" Version="1.0.0.0">
        <ExcludeAssets>none</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
...
```

But, I could not make it work using a compile switch or macro.

Comment: What problem are you trying to accomplish?  What nuget package are you trying to switch between?  Different versions of the same nuget?  Or a different implementation alltogether?  What advantage are you seeking by accomplishing this?

Comment: Decompile - `.nupkg` files are just `.zip` files with another extension and can be unzipped with any zip utility. PackageReference can have a condition. What else do you actually need?

Comment: @NightOwl888 How would you do that in compile-time? Also, I want to avoid conflict with the NuGet package manager by doing something that is not normal to do.

Comment: @ArjunSivaprasadam what is preventing you from having both packages installed at the same time?  Also, not sure the implications of "reaches its lifetime soon".  Are you implying that the package will simply cease working at a certain time?  I just don't understand at all how what you are proposing is going to help with your situation.  The alternative library presumably has an entirely different API, so I fail to see how switching out one with the other could be done without code changes unless you put usages of the library behind your own abstractions.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I'm using a licensed paid NuGet package which reaches its lifetime soon. So I want to have a complete alternative NuGet package which takes over that functionality based on a compile switch.

Additionally, the NuGet package is priced based on the number of developers and I want to remove the usage of that NuGet package during other development.

Comment: Yes, you already said all of that.  Apparently you deleted your earlier comment?  But what you just retyped was what I was responding to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @KirkWoll, I missed adding the last two lines in the previous comment about additional developers. The problem is that additional developers don't have access to the NuGet package License.

Comment: @ArjunSivaprasadam - Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the body of your question to add additional details (rather than posting them in comments). The way your question is worded, it is not possible for others to determine what your goal is, what you have tried, or how your results differed from your desired results. "I could not make it work using a compile switch or macro" is not an explanation that is helpful to people to answer your question when you haven't even described what "it" is.

Comment: @ArjunSivaprasadam - Why do you need to "decompile" a `.nupkg` at compile time? A NuGet package can be uniquely identified with its ID and version, so what is the point?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I don't need to decompile. I want a conditional compile. I was just experimenting with your comment and attempting to stitch together another idea from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After a lot of tinkering. This is the final solution that turned out to satisfy all my requirements. It is a bit long and I have added all the findings relevant to this question.*

*Before I get into implementation, this is my setup
#(.NET 6.0, C# 10, WPF Project, VS2022)*

**Steps involved!**

1. Declaration of a compile switch
2. Prebuild conditional switch for compiling/ignoring the Nuget Package
3. Context switch in the XAML file.
4. Compile switches to isolate the package in the C# file.

**Step1**: Declaration of a compile switch (NUGET_ENABLE)

Project -> Proprties -> Conditional Compilation Symbols

```
$(DefineConstants);NUGET_ENABLE
```

> *(Note: A value cannot be assigned to the NUGET_ENABLE, The NUGET_ENABLE has to be renamed or removed for Removing this NuGet Usage.)*

**Step2**: Prebuild conditional switch for compiling/ignoring the Nuget Package

Open the *myproject.csproj* (Project file).
Use a regex expression to find the specific compile switch from $(DefineConstants), If NUGET_ENABLE exists compile the NuGet package.

(Reference: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2022))

```
    <Choose>
    <When Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch($(DefineConstants), '^(.*;)*NUGET_ENABLE(;.*)*$'))">
        <!-- When NUGET_ENABLE is defined. -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="nugetPackage2Exclude" Version=""/>
        </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    </Choose>
```

**Step3**: Context switch in the XAML file

> (***Fair Warning!**: The `<mc:AlternateContent>` Tag may prevent the loading of the Design preview window (Xaml Designer) in VS or Blend.*)

(Reference: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732307/does-xaml-have-a-conditional-compiler-directive-for-debug-mode))

*Step3a*: Edit the assembly file to add a XAML Switch

```
#if NUGET_ENABLE 
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("nuget_enable", "NameSpace")]
#endif // NUGET_ENABLE
```

*Step3b*: Add the XAML file headers

```
    ...
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:nuget="http://schemas.nugetPackage2Exclude.etc/"
     xmlns:nugetEnabled="nuget_enable"
    ...
     mc:Ignorable="d nuget" // d is optional!
    ...
```

*Step3c*: Add the XAML context switch

```
    <mc:AlternateContent>
        <mc:Choice Requires="nugetEnabled">
                <!--<code calling the nuget>-->
        </mc:Choice>
        <mc:Fallback>
        
        </mc:Fallback>
    </mc:AlternateContent>
```

**Step4**:Compile switches to isolate the package in the C# file.

```
#if NUGET_ENABLE 
// Code
#endif
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a package that uses SystemTextJson or NewtonsoftJson depending on a compilation defined constant that the consumer is built with,  so only one of the two assemblies is output as a dependency.  Is that what your code here is doing?

Comment: I was doing a WPF application, So I needed the conditional compilation in 3 domains, one in XAML, one in C# and one for the project file targeting NuGet packages. Yes, this solution should match your scenario perfectly @PeterMorris