# Compiler arguments with XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, baml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XAML Conditional Compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213576/xaml-conditional-compilation)

In C#, I can do the following in the code.

```
#if COMPILING_AS_WINDOWS_PHONE_7
    //some random code
#else
    //some random code
#endif
```

This allows me to have several projects that compile differently by using the compiler arguments of the projects. In other words, I don't have to reinvent the wheel every time.

However, how can I do this with XAML? I can't seem to find anything anywhere about this online.

Comment: I did see that link. I don't know how the link the answerer sent would help me, and he didn't explain it very well.

Comment: I can explain that given idiom of XAML coditionals lies to the ground of a partial class compilation, that is an idea: "if at compile time you provide more details of your class, that will lead to more specialzed implementation of your class". In any way, in XAML you should definetly define ALL possibilities of your XAML usage, so your XAML will be even bigger, which eliminates the idiom of #if #elseif preprocessor definitions. You really will not like the idea to hold all crap for widows phone 7 for EACH control in Windows 8 XAML controls, for example.

Comment: I only need it in scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** control XAML, because **XAML should always have auto-generated code behind** in .NET, which will be compiled automatically and ignore all prerocessor definitions.

You can use comments and do this manually with **<!-- -->** comment symbols

The only working solution - is completely convert your XAML definitions as fully encoded as C# class, so using **pure C#** classes into a class control library. Alternatively, you can use managed C++ for control composition.

The only disadvantage  is that will make it hard to develop, maintain, read, and change by hand. The advantage is that you can use one of the code generation tools for XAML.

And, lastly, using **#if #endif** you can use one code library / code sources for both **windows phone** / **8** development, but in my experience, **it's better to use partial classes** and **common code base** (you can add a file as reference to the project).

Comment: Look at the comment made to my question. The possible duplicate. It seems promising. Can you research it and help me understand it?